# Как удвоить время обработки формы?

Tags: php, форма

Есть простая форма ввода пароля.
Как удваивать время обработки формы для одного ip.
Поможет ли это защититься от спамеров и ботов ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В сессии храните счётчик неудачных попыток, и ставьте `sleep( pow(2,$count))` — с каждой попыткой пауза будет всё больше: 2, 4, 8, 16с ...

После 10 неудачных блокируйте сессию, после 3 десятков разных заблокированных сессий с одного ip — блокируйте ip (значит, злодей догадался сбрасывать куки).

При общем резком росте числа неудачных попыток по сайту, либо пересмотрите код, либо паникуйте : )

**Upd.** Одно лишь это удваивание времени каждый раз не сильно поможет от ботов. В Joomla, например, делается так. Выдавая форму для ввода пароля, сайт создаёт сессию, и генерит неий уникальный параметр, который сохраняется в сессии. Он же пишется в виде скрытого `<input type="hidden"...>` в форме для пароля.

Пришли данные на логин — смотрим, соответствует ли тот скрытый параметр тому значению, что сохранено в сессии. Если нет — такой запрос можно не обрабатывать дальше. Либо это бот, либо отключены куки.

Comment: а как быть людям с одним ip(vpn, прокси или с телефона) ?

Comment: Сессия же. С одного IP может хоть целый завод в сеть выйти, с каждым будет индивидуальная сессия.

Comment: боты обычно без сессии сидят ) и без кук.

Comment: А те, кто без кук и сессии сразу идут лесом. Выдавая форму для ввода пароля, в сессию УЖЕ пишется некий уникальный параметр. Он же должен присутствовать в виде скрытого поля в форме с паролем. Пришел пароль — смотрим: есть ли в сессии параметр, равный пришедшему вместе с формой. Нет? — "Бендер, перелогиньтесь!"

Comment: а sleep на каком уровне ставить?, на JS, PHP?

Comment: На сервере, конечно, клиент на своей стороне хозяин, захочет -- js вообще выполнять не будет.

Comment: sleep с удвоением тогда не очень хорошая вещь... 30 секунд превысит и страница будет возвращаться как превышен интервал.

Comment: Первые N попыток можно делать эту задержку, а затем просто отмалчиваться.

Answer (score 1):

Можно без удваивания, поставить `sleep` на несколько секунд

Второй вариант - замерить время обработки (тем же `time()` в начале и конце обработки), а после поставить [`sleep`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sleep.php)/[`usleep`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usleep.php)/[`time_nanosleep`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.time-nanosleep.php) с количество времени, потраченном на обработку формы.

Comment: Да, первый вариант каждый раз испытываешь на себе, когда по SSH неудачно заходишь. Пароль правильный - проблем нет, вот вам терминал; ошиблись - извольте подождать пару-тройку секунд.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, хранить время генерации формы, и сравнивать с временем когда данные от формы пришли. Если например прошло меньше 3 секунд, значит это отправил спамер, или бот )

Время можно например:

- записывать в базу (предпочтительне)
- хранить в сессии, куках
- записывать в скрытое поле формы (тут лучше еще защититься, и добавить хитрый хэш от времени, если хэш от пришедшего времени не совпадает с хэшем то дату поменяли)

Answer (score 0):

проверяем `ip` и `session`
если нету такого
пишем в базу `ip` и `session`
Выполняем скрипт
делаем response с флагом `done = true`

на фронтэнде
если пришел `done as true`
на кнопку `submit` ставим `disabled`